# Scheme - Function call without name

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, racket

I'm using DrRacket for implementing my code in scheme. I'm new with this language and  I need some help with my homework. My teacher wants me to call a function from console, and she does not want me to call it with its name.

> **This is not allowed => *(function-name 'John (X p c f F g K : : 1 4))***

Instead using that notation, i have to call my function with out name.

> **This is what she wants => *('John (X p c f F g K : : 1 4))***

Is there any way to define a function without name and call it? I searched a lot on internet but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Ask your teacher what she really wants.

Comment: The system must process set password requests in the form of
('John (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example doesn't make much sense. The second snippet is just a list of parameters, at *some point* you have to pass a real procedure. One alternative to "call a function without name" would be to use a `lambda` expression, which is an anonymous procedure... for instance, this:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(square 4)
=> 16
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 4) ; look ma, no name!
=> 16
```

You can even define recursive procedures in terms of `lambda`s, read about the Y-combinator for additional details.

**EDIT**

After reading the comments - if you simply need to pass a list of parameters to a function, use this:

```
(apply function-name list-of-parameters)
```

Comment: " The system must process set password requests in the form of
('John (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :)) " this is what she wants. And how will i pass a list of parameters to a function?

Comment: Notice that you completely misunderstood what your teacher was asking. If you receive the parameters in a list, you can call the function like this: `(apply function-name list-of-parameters)`. What your teacher asks doesn't imply, in any way, that the name of the function can't be used.

Comment: Yeah, i knew that i misunderstood it. List of parameters thing will help, ty